# Problem "cannot redeclare" when the file is included more times - PHP

Tags: php, loops, cron, redeclare

i'm trying to run the same file more times (again and again...)
But i have this problem `Cannot redeclare function`

This is my code inside the file `test.php`

```
$word= hello();
print_r($word);

include('test.php');    


function hello(){
    $x= "ok";
    return $x;
}
```

When the function print the word i want to run again the same file with `include`
The problem is `Cannot redeclare hello()`

**DETAILS**

To run the same file again i could to use a `cronjob` like to do for other files but in this project i don't know when to run again the file. I must wait the execution of code inside `test.php`. 
The execution's time is variable and so i can't to set a cronjob when to run the file every 1 minute or 2 minute.

**EDIT: explain more**

I have a file called "A.php" where every two minutes two other files are created containing two different arrays (which we will call for simplicity array1.php and array2.php).

Every two minutes a cron job executes "A. php" and the code inside it destroys and creates the two new array files.

In my new project ("test.php") I use the arrays of the two files to send notifications to my telegram.
Notifications are sent only and exclusively if there is something new inside these 2 arrays.

If I used a cronjob for "test.php" I could have a problem: if "A.php" for some reason failed to update the two arrays, "test.php" sends the same notifications twice.

For this reason I would like to run "test.php" at the end of the file:
at the beginning of test.php extrapolate filemtime () of the two arrays and at the end of "test.php" extract again the filemtime () of the two arrays.
If the two files have been updated (they have a different timestamp) I include "test.php" again, otherwise I sleep 10 seconds and repeat the comparison.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? You never explained it in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57713824/when-file-php-is-end-is-possible-to-run-same-file)

Comment: Everything about including a file from itself seems misguided.

Comment: @Barmar in the previous question didn't work because there was a stupid error and i don't know like delete that question. Anyway now i edit this question and exmplain more. Give me 1 minute

Comment: Do you know about LOOPS yet? If you want to do something more than once write a loop

Comment: You may also find `sleep()` useful from what you say.

Comment: @Barmar please read the edit

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes i want to use it, please read the edit

Comment: Have you considered using a database ?

Comment: In the last 60 seconds, yes :D maybe is the only way... using a cronjob for example every two minutes, save the filemtime() of those two files (with array) in a database or external file and run the code inside "test.php" only if filemtime() is change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your cron job so it runs `test.php` after `A.php`, but only if `A.php` is successful.

```
*/2 * * * * php A.php && php test.php
```

`A.php` should exit with a non-zero code if it's not successful; it can do this with

```
die(1);
```

If you want an additional check, `test.php` can safe the timestamps of the files in another file. When it starts up, it can read that file to get the previous timestamps, and compare the current timestamps with it. If they haven't changed, it doesn't send the notification.

Comment: is a good idea and i will accept it but i have only a doubt...what happen if i run cronjob every 2 minutes and to send notifications it takes 3 minutes ?

Comment: That might be a problem with this solution.